# Lovely flow rate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

How can we calculate the measure of the air flow rate when it is coming out of the balloon? (I mean that which parameter affects that? For example, the measure of balloons neck or the ratios or something else?)

Comment: You've already asked that question (and received an answer), why do you ask it again?

Comment: Also, why did you apply the [tag:general-relativity] tag here?

Comment: If you were thinking on this , you understood that this is a different question. I asked before : What is the measure of the flow rate in the tube  but now I asked in the real nature . (means that : My new question said that this is relate to some of the other parameter)